# What did Merida say?

Tags: ralph-breaks-the-internet

[Merida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merida_(Disney)) is a Pixar character and has a nice Scottish accent, but what did she say in *Ralph Breaks The Internet*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Movie

According to IMDb she says:

> Arr! Lang may yer lum reek, and may a moose ne'er leave your girnal with a tear drop in his eye! Haste ye back, me lassie!

[Dictionary of the Scots](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/lum_n1_v1) cites this quote:

> Lang may your lum reek — a common expression to wish someone prosperity and plenty.

(It literally translates to "long may your chimney smoke".)

The next part is part of a traditional [Scottish toast](https://josvg.home.xs4all.nl/scot/card/index.html) which translates to:

> May a mouse never leave your girnal
> With a tear drop in his eye

(A girnal is essentially a pantry.)

Lastly, [according to the Dictionary of the Scots](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/heest) "Haste ye back" is:

> an invitation to visit one = “Come back, etc. soon!”

And "me lassie" pretty clearly translates to "my girl".

Here's a clip:

#### Trailer

According to the [BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/5w7qMSfbqtJX8KSwl07SfZP/has-disney-taken-aim-at-the-scottish-accent-in-new-ralph-film), the line is:

> I gie ma mammy a cake, she turned in tae a big bear and my auld yin tried tae dae her in. If that’s no a pure mess, I don’t know whit is!

(The spelling could either be something like the above or closer to Standard English: I give my mommy a cake, she turned into a big bear and my auld yin tried to do her in. If that’s not a pure mess, I don’t know what is!)

["Auld yin"](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/sndns149) literally translates to "old one", but means "one's parent" (from watching *Brave* it's clear she's referring to her father).

---

Here's the clip:

Comment: ‘Auld yin’ almost always refers to one's father. I've never heard it used of one's mother, but that's not to say it can't be

Comment: Well, I think I know which of the three suitors Merida went with.

Answer (score 13):

**In the trailer**

According to this Scottish YouTuber, she says:

> I gave my mummy a cake, she turned into a big bear, my own dad tried to do her in, if that's not a pure mess I don't know what is!

At [this point](https://youtu.be/p7Yt8HwmJfk?t=141) in the video.

---

**In the movie**

Although apparently this trailer scene doesn't actually make it into the movie. [This is the scene in the movie](https://youtu.be/_2jssbQZHdI).

According to the [this person in the comments there](https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCitF3afZtXkZKAuIOw1ICbA), she says this:

> Ack! Lang may yer lum reek, and may a moose ne'er leave your girnal with a tear drop in his eye! Haste Ye Back, Me Lassie!
>
> Lang may yer lum reek means "long may your chimney smoke" or, I wish you well and a long and healthy life .
>
> May a moose ne'er leave your girnal with a tear drop in his eye!
>   Moose is her saying 'mouse', but in her accent. And a girnal is where they'd store oats and meals. So essentially may a mouse never leave where you store your oats with a tear in their eye. If the mouse has a tear, it means you're out of oats and food. So she's saying she hopes for the opposite. So what Merida is saying is that she hopes Venelope has a long a healthy life(may your chimney always smoke) as well wishing that she will always have resources to survive, but also can be a nice way of asking that nobody ever leave her presence disappointed. The opposite of these wishes would be a cold home, sickness, and no food.
>
> She ends it with Haste Ye Back, Me Lassie, which is her way of saying "I hope/want to see you again soon, my friend."
>
> So Merida is saying essentially "May you have a long and healthy life, full of resources and easy goings. I hope to see you again soon, my friend."